# Is there a good summary of all nuclear fusion approaches?

Tags: nuclear-physics, fusion, nuclear-engineering

I am pretty sure, that during last 60 years of well-funded research a lot of ideas on nuclear fusion were already tried and ruled out.

Is there some summary describing all of them and why they didn't work? (I am looking something going way beyond just Tokamak / Stellarator / Laser ICF / Z-Pinch).

Comment: Your list will be  more or less complete if you include cold fusion  and the dust fusion mentioned recently. Hot plasmas are expensive to create and maintain and the research projects were all very visible.

Comment: Generally you would look for review articles, but they will vary enormously on their coverage of lines of inquiry that didn't work out. Actual that could have been 'they will vary enormously.' but it will be even more so than usual in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

List of fusion power technologies: 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_fusion_power_technologies

Other more well-designed fusion concepts are not fully tested yet due to lack of funding: http://www.crossfirefusion.com/nuclear-fusion-reactor/crossfire-fusion-reactor.html